# How to see the response in Postman with Header and Request parameter for API

Tags: android, swift, api, request, postman

our api contains header and Request parameter like below

**This is the URL**: http://itaag.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/register/

**Method**: POST

**Http header**:

deviceid    -   unique id of the device (no validation for now. takes any value)

userType    -   personal or business

key         -   phone number or email id (phone number is validated for any 10 digits)

**Request** :

**Request parameter name**: "registrationdetails"

**Sample Request user**:

```
 {"firstName":"Sample", 
  "lastName":"Test",
  "email":"sm@gmail.com", 
  "gender":"male",
  "ageGroup":"40-50"}
```

**Response Should be like this**:

{"userId":"dfsfewrwebegergbfdbert"} {"businessId":"refsfsdkkdsfsnjkfsdfhidshfih"}

Possible errors:

General error

Invalid email

Invalid phone number

Invalid GST

Notes:

Use http  response code  200 for success and http response code 400 for failure.

If i give request like below mentioned answer then i am getting like this:
   [image]

How do i get response in postman, please help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Reference for request and parameter]**As per my understanding you can get response by doing this steps:**[image: Add all parameters ,headers and url as added in image to get response]

I hope it will help you.
Thank you.

Comment: headers okay, what about parameters and request

Comment: add parameters in body-> form-data and request as added in image

Comment: please show how and where you write parameter and request in postmen..

Comment: I just added image for request and parameters

Comment: where did u add the parameter..? i. have given like u.. once look at above my edited post.. added image

Comment: i have validate otp for 9876543210.. pls try this 10 digt random number for correct response.. why i am not gettin response?

Comment: OTP is not validate for 9876543210 .I get same response